# Backbone.js - How can I show a saving gif when I loop through and save my models?

Tags: backbone.js

I am allowing the user to press a Save button and so in the event method for that button I need to save all existing models in the collection and destroy any models that were deleted before the button was pressed.

What I would like to do is display an ajax gif while this is all happening. How can I find out when all model.save() and model.destroy() methods are finished?

Here is the method I call when the Save button is pressed:

```
  Save: function() {
                var response = confirm("Are you sure you want to save?");

                if (response == true) {
                    // save items
                    var self = this;
                    this.collection.each(function(item) {
                        self.RemoveTempId(item);  // if temp id exists remove it
                        item.save();
                    });
                    // destroy items in the trashcan
                    for (var i = this.trashCan.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        this.trashCan[i].destroy();
                    }
                }
            },
```

How can I tap into an event when they are all completed so I can hide my ajax gif?
Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Each of these method (`save` and `destroy`) returns a promise. You can wait for multiple promise to finish using the jQuery `when` method. e.g.:

```
$.when( model.save(), model2.destroy() ).then(function() { /* do stuff */ });
```

Of course this should be adapted to your used cases (because you loop through each model, so you'll probably use an array and `.apply()` the array of deferred on `when`), but you get the main idea.

Also I'd suggest separating the `confirm` dialog and the loading gif inside a view out of the model/collection. This will create a better separation of concern and a more manageable code.

An example with an array of deferreds:

```
var defs = [];
this.collection.each(function(item) {
    defs.push( item.save() );
});

$.when.apply( null, defs ).then(function() {
    /* everything is saved */
});
```

Comment: `save` returns `false` if validation fails, so you may not want to chain all of the requests together exactly like that.

Comment: @WiredPrairie In fact, you can pass any value to `when`. If it's not a promise, it's considered as resolved and the result is passed in the next function. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/

Comment: (I wanted to just point it out that it doesn't always return a jqxhr, and that calling `save` without looking at the result may produce unexpected results).

Comment: How can this work since I am using parameters? The syntax is driving me crazy.

Comment: @Smith can you be clearer about what you mean? I don't understand what you mean sorry

Comment: How can I convert  this.collection.each(function(item) { item.save() }    to something that uses .apply()?

Answer (score 0):

When user agrees to save after your prompt, just show your GIF Image on the page and set its position where you want to show it. Probably, you should display it at center of screen.

Pass a success and error handler in your save method as options hash and hide your GIF image there.

Take a look at [Backbone Model save documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-save)

Some pseudo code goes like this:-

```
saveModel: function() {
    //Show image now. Use CSS to make it visible.
    $('#gifSelector').show();

    model.save({ 'x':1, 'y':2}, // The default attributes in your model which we wanna save
    success: function() {
        alert('Model has been saved');
        //Hide Gid image
        $('#gifSelector').hide();
    },
    error: function(e) {
        alert('Encountered some problem in saving model');
        // Hide GIF image
        $('#gifSelector').hide();
    }
}
```

**One Suggestion**: Since you will be calling this method for each model and everytime we don't want to query DOM to get GIF image using its selector. Its better to store a global reference to it and show/hide it using that reference. It will be faster ;)

Comment: How is this going to work when you have, say, 11 models being saved?

Comment: Yea, my problem is that I want to only show the ajax gif once and have it hide when all models are saved or destroyed.

Comment: Whenever every model is saved/destroyed, your GIF image will be shown/hidden for each model. Since you have run a loop to save/destroy all the models, user won't be able to know whether you are showing and hiding GIF for each model or it is done for whole collection. Just try it, I think it will work.